# Two PCs, Same Network, Completely Different Internet Speeds

Tags: windows-10, networking, ethernet, speedtest

Unsure what has happened over the past month. I've noticed on my gaming PC the speeds I receive are much lower than what they used to be.

Specs:

Game PC:

```
i9-10900k
2080ti
Asus Z490-E Gaming Mobo
Windows 10 1909
Intel Ethernet Controller I225V
```

Stream PC:

```
i7-7700k
1080
Asus Prime H270
windows 10 1909
```

Both PCs have Cat6 cables.
My Stream PC is receiving 900mbs download & upload speed.
My Game PC is receiving 150-200mbs down & up.

I've tried updating drivers for the port
Intel Ethernet Controller I225V.
I've tried swapping cables, rebooting router & PC.
I've done network resets in CMD along with enabling and disabling
Windows auto-tuning, same outcome.

Any advice or tips would be great, kinda frustrating the better PC is causing an issue.

Comment: Why is the post tagged as "wireless-networking"? Have you tried another network adapter on the slower PC?

Comment: MB/s or Mbps? 1 MB/s = 8 Mbps.

Comment: Please don't respond using answers, they're for answers only. You can [edit] the question to improve it. Capitalization is essential, there's no such unit as MBPS. It's either MB/s (with uppercase `B` which stands for bytes) or Mbps (with lowercase `b` which stands for bits).

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard on your gaming pc has some issues with it's Network Interface Card (NIC) > **Intel® I225-V 2.5Gb Ethernet** , known issues. I am facing the same problem too and did some researching a few weeks back.

A quick google search of the network card above shows a myriad of issues. Software fixes don't seem to be viable, such as installing/updating to the latest drivers.

[image]

You can try your luck with getting it swapped with ASUS by emailing them. Do remember to include your serial number to speed up the process, if need be.